# Animate (slide in) new panel to replace current panel's contents?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to change the contents of an `Ext.List`. I'm trying to change the content to a new panel, although I don't need more list elements.

This seems to replace the contents, but how do I animate the change?

```
onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
    console.log('Disclose more info for ' + record.get('name'));
    var panel1 = Ext.getCmp('panel-1');
    panel1.remove(Ext.getCmp('panel-1'));
    panel1.add(Ext.getCmp('panel-2'));
    panel1.doLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is to have the `panel-1` and `panel-2` as items in a different panel and then switch between them. Example:

```
    var detailPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id:'detailPanel',
            scroll:'vertical',
            tpl:'<h1>{text}</h1>'
    });

   var list = new Ext.List({
        id :'theList',
        itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
        store: store1,
        width: '100%',
        scroll:false
    });

   var panel =  new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        id:'thePanel',
        layout: 'card',
        cardSwitchAnimation:'slide',
        scroll:'vertical',
         items:[list, detailPanel]
    });
```

Then you can update the detailPanel like this `Ext.getCmp('detailPanel').update(record.data);` and switch to it. `Ext.getCmp('thePanel').setActiveItem(1,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});`

The second argument of the setActiveItem is the animation config. object. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Panel

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd been implicitly using CardLayout with lists, and I forgot it existed on its own in the first place.